# How to get Firebase Combined Message in Background app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Reading documentation of firebase about cloud message in [combined way](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages), I've had problems to get data message in android device.

```
var payload = {
    notification: {
        title: "Test",
        body: "Test body"
    },
    data: {    
        score: "850",
        close: "635.67"
    }
};
```

I expect to get data field at 'onMessageReceived' in android device, but I got only a notification message. I tried to tap the message and I still got nothing at 'onMessageReceived'.

I've add a intent filter to trigger the main activity, add 'clickAction'(as referred in firebase reference) and 'click_action'(as I saw in some questions) in notification payload, and I also got the same.

MANIFEST

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<meta-data
android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
android:resource="@color/blue" />


<service
android:name=".connection.TestFirebaseMessagingService">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
</intent-filter>
</service>


<service
android:name=".connection.TestFirebaseIDService">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
</intent-filter>
</service>
```

Java Code:

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "TestFirebase";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    LogNotification.d(TAG, "NOTIFICATION - From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());


    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        LogNotification.d(TAG, "NOTIFICATION - Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        LogNotification.d(TAG, "NOTIFICATION - Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

    }
}

}
```

Some tips?

Comment: Add your Java code, please

Comment: Ok, I add manifest too. Done.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `notification` key in your payload then the message becomes a notification message.

Notification messages are displayed automatically when the app is in background.

When the notification is clicked FCM launches your main activity (or another one if you specified `click_action`)

In the activity you can use `getIntent()` to get the intent that launched the activity.

If your activity was launched by FCM you will find the `data` payload in the intent used to launch the activity.

Comment: specified like click_action? cause I saw in firebase documentation as clickAction. Are both correct?

Comment: It depends which language / context you are using. If you are sending an HTTP request then the parameter is called click_action.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support